# Using Spring 5.0 WebClient to make asynchronous calls throws Connection refused with few successful calls

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot, webclient, spring-webflux

I am trying to make asynchronous post requests via WebClient as this is the preferred way when using Springframework 5.0.

here is my Server code:

```
package com.example.demo;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
@Slf4j
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/createCustomer", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE, consumes = "text/plain")
    public Customer sendStream(@RequestBody String number) throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(40);
        return new Customer(number, "random" + number);
    }

    @Data
    @AllArgsConstructor
    class Customer {
        String id;
        String name;
    }


}
```

The client code I have is:

```
    package com.example.demo2;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.BodyInserters;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient;
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;
import reactor.core.scheduler.Schedulers;

import java.util.stream.IntStream;

@SpringBootApplication
@Slf4j
public class Demo2Application implements CommandLineRunner {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Demo2Application.class, args);
    }


    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        WebClient webClient = WebClient.create("http://localhost:8080");
        IntStream.range(0, 100000).forEach(i -> {
            Flux.merge(
                    webClient
                            .post()
                            .uri("/createCustomer")
                            .body(BodyInserters.fromObject(String.valueOf(i)))
                            .retrieve().bodyToMono(String.class)
            )
                    .parallel()
                    .runOn(Schedulers.single())
                    .subscribe(log::info);


        });

    }
}
```

And I get the following exceptions when I run this code with some successful runs.

```
2019-01-18 00:39:34.716  INFO 38236 --- [       single-1] com.example.demo2.Demo2Application       : {"id":"1049","name":"random1049"} 2019-01-18 00:39:34.731 ERROR 38236
--- [       single-1] reactor.core.scheduler.Schedulers        : Scheduler worker in group main failed with an uncaught exception

reactor.core.Exceptions$ErrorCallbackNotImplemented: io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: no further information: localhost/127.0.0.1:8080 Caused by: io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: no further information: localhost/127.0.0.1:8080   at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]  at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:779) ~[na:na]    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:327) ~[netty-transport-4.1.31.Final.jar:4.1.31.Final]     at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:340) ~[netty-transport-4.1.31.Final.jar:4.1.31.Final]    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:636) ~[netty-transport-4.1.31.Final.jar:4.1.31.Final]     at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:583) ~[netty-transport-4.1.31.Final.jar:4.1.31.Final]   at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:500) ~[netty-transport-4.1.31.Final.jar:4.1.31.Final]    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:462) ~[netty-transport-4.1.31.Final.jar:4.1.31.Final]    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:897) ~[netty-common-4.1.31.Final.jar:4.1.31.Final]   at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]     Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException:  Assembly trace from producer [reactor.core.publisher.MonoCreate] :  reactor.core.publisher.Mono.create(Mono.java:183)   reactor.netty.resources.PooledConnectionProvider.acquire(PooledConnectionProvider.java:121) Error has been observed by the following operator(s):   |_  Mono.create ⇢ reactor.netty.resources.PooledConnectionProvider.acquire(PooledConnectionProvider.java:121)   |_  Mono.create ⇢ reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientConnect$MonoHttpConnect.subscribe(HttpClientConnect.java:289)     |_  Mono.retry ⇢ reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientConnect$MonoHttpConnect.subscribe(HttpClientConnect.java:324)  |_  Mono.flatMapMany ⇢ reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientFinalizer.responseConnection(HttpClientFinalizer.java:85)    |_  Flux.next ⇢ org.springframework.http.client.reactive.ReactorClientHttpConnector.connect(ReactorClientHttpConnector.java:112)    |_  Mono.doOnRequest ⇢ org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ExchangeFunctions$DefaultExchangeFunction.exchange(ExchangeFunctions.java:104)  |_  Mono.doOnCancel ⇢ org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ExchangeFunctions$DefaultExchangeFunction.exchange(ExchangeFunctions.java:105)   |_  Mono.map ⇢ org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ExchangeFunctions$DefaultExchangeFunction.exchange(ExchangeFunctions.java:106)  |_  Mono.switchIfEmpty ⇢ org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.DefaultWebClient$DefaultRequestBodyUriSpec.exchange(DefaultWebClient.java:319)    |_  Mono.flatMap ⇢ org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.DefaultWebClient$DefaultResponseSpec.bodyToMono(DefaultWebClient.java:429)  |_  Flux.parallel ⇢ com.example.demo2.Demo2Application.lambda$run$0(Demo2Application.java:35)       |_  Flux.parallel ⇢ com.example.demo2.Demo2Application.lambda$run$0(Demo2Application.java:35)           |_  Flux.parallel ⇢ com.example.demo2.Demo2Application.lambda$run$0(Demo2Application.java:35)
                |_  Flux.parallel ⇢ com.example.demo2.Demo2Application.lambda$run$0(Demo2Application.java:35)
                    |_  Flux.parallel ⇢ com.example.demo2.Demo2Application.lambda$run$0(Demo2Application.java:35)
                        |_  Flux.parallel ⇢ com.example.demo2.Demo2Application.lambda$run$0(Demo2Application.java:35)
                            |_  Flux.parallel ⇢ com.example.demo2.Demo2Application.lambda$run$0(Demo2Application.java:35)
                                |_  Flux.parallel ⇢ com.example.demo2.Demo2Application.lambda$run$0(Demo2Application.java:35)
                                |_  ParallelFlux.runOn ⇢ com.example.demo2.Demo2Application.lambda$run$0(Demo2Application.java:36)

Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information    ... 10 common frames omitted
```

What am I doing wrong, I tried to limit number of threads, but that did not help as can be seen in the client code where I am using single thread.

Any help will be much appreciated.

is this a bug?

Comment: You `sleep` your server threads then you thrash your server with thousands of requests. Result? All your server threads are sleeping and the request queue fills up. Eventually the server tells you to go away because it's having a nap! Solution? Standard spiel about rate limiting and graceful degradation. TL;DR: your server is dumb.

Comment: yep, I am trying to mimic a realistic scenario where a server request could take about 30ms. I am trying to reduce the number of threads how do I reduce so as I do not thrash it?

Comment: You are using non-blocking IO! Learn what that means perhaps? "_sources are subscribed to eagerly_"

Comment: Sure I will do @BoristheSpider I am a newbie please do you mind elobarating a little on how I could my server intelligent, its using the standard spring-boot netty with default configuration.

Comment: For example you could do you processing on another thread allowing the request thread to return to the pool, say by returning a `DeferredResult` or `Mono` from the request method. Then before beginning processing check requests in flight and send a nice rejection to the client. Fundamentally though if you DoS your server you're going to have to reject requests somehow.